# Multiple Cursors versus Multiple Connections

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm building an automation in Python which fetches some data from a database table and populates an excel sheet. I'm using cx_Oracle module for setting up a connection. There are around 44 queries, and around 2 million rows of data are fetched for each query, which makes this script run for an hour. So I'm planning to use threading module to speed up the process. Although I'm confused whether to use multiple connections (around 4) or have less connections (say, 2) and multiple cursors per connection.

The queries are independent of each other. They are `select` statements to fetch the data and are not manipulating the table in any way.

I just need some pros and cons of using both approaches so that I can decide how to go about the script. I tried searching for it a lot, but curiously I'm not able to find any relevant piece of information at all. If you point me to any kind of blog post, even that will be really helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An Oracle connection can really do just one thing at a time. Specifically while a database session can have multiple open cursors at any one time, it can only be executing one of them.

As such, you won't see any improvement by having multiple cursors in a single connection.

That said, depending on the bottleneck, you MIGHT not see any improvement from going with multiple connections either. It might be choked on bandwidth in returning the data, disk access etc. If you can code in such a way as to keep the number of threads / connections variable, then you can tweak until you find the best result.

Comment: Great! Kinda answers my question. Thank you :)

Comment: A side note: when dealing with large datasets, don't forget to tune https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize